# Runtime Error in Google Kick Start Round A for Python

Tags: python, runtime-error

For an unknown reason, the system says my code has an error while my editor works perfectly. Any idea why my code doesn't work? (To make it more clear I am testing my program (not submitting) on the given input in the kickstart editor.)

```py
case = int(input())
for i in range(case):
  price = 0
  amount = 0
  num, budget = input().split()
  houses = sorted(input().split(), key=int)
  for house in houses:
    price += int(house)
    if price > int(budget):
      break
    amount += 1
  print(f'Case #{i+1}: {amount}')
```

The input I gave to the test

```
Input
3
4 100
20 90 40 90
4 50
30 30 10 10
3 300
999 999 999

Expected Output
Case #1: 2
Case #2: 3
Case #3: 0

Result
RE
```

The problem I'm solving (By Request)-

Question:
Problem
There are N houses for sale. The i-th house costs Ai dollars to buy. You have a budget of B dollars to spend.

What is the maximum number of houses you can buy?

Input
The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a single line containing the two integers N and B. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is Ai, the cost of the i-th house.

Output
For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the maximum number of houses you can buy.

Comment: What is the system? What is the error?

Comment: They don't tell us the error, unfortunately.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: With some research, it seems like there's a weird convention you have to follow on Google Kickstart - https://www.techrbun.com/google-coding-competitions-runtime-error-solved/. The thing is they don't tell us, so I need a person who did this competition with python.

Comment: I'm trying to pass the test

Comment: I'm going to guess that you simply aren't doing what you think you're doing with the code. What do you think you're doing? In the code?

Comment: No, I don't you understand the question, this is a past problem for a Google competition. I'm getting an error in the competition's editor but it works perfectly with other editors.

Comment: Try removing the f-string, replace it with format. What version of python is the system using?

Comment: Why can't you describe the task or link to it?

Comment: @superbrain. OP did. The issue is with a runtime error in the code

Comment: the language is python3

Comment: Let me try replacing f string with .format()

Comment: @superbrain. I've identified the problem based on the info provided. See attached answer

Comment: @MadPhysicist OP did *after* you said they did. Are you a clairvoyant? :-)

Comment: @superbrain. We just weren't reading the question right at first. OP was showing perfectly working code. It doesn't matter what the code actually does or what the problem it's solving is. The issue is that it's working in one interpreter and not in another. Once I figured that out, the answer was obvious.

Comment: @superbrain. The problem with being new is not so much that you can't figure stuff out or do research, it's that you don't know terminology or how to phrase things just right to make the veterans understand. This is a case in point. Perfectly ok question at the core, plenty of info, etc, but misleading phrasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the page that describes the different languages and packages: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/faq. Look under the Platform section and find Python 3. The specs are

> - Python 3:
>
>   - 3.5.3 (package: python3.5)
>
>     - numpy 1.16.2 (pip install numpy)
>     - scipy 1.2.1 (pip install scipy)
>   - python3.5 Solution.py

F-strings and some other features were not introduced until Python 3.6. Replace the last line with

```
print('Case #{}: {}'.format(i + 1, amount))
```